# Let $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=5$. Find $\gcd(25ab^2, a^4 + b^4)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a,b\in\mathbb Z$  such that $\gcd(a,b)=5$. Find $\gcd(25ab^2, a^4+b^4)=d$.

This is all I managed to think of: $a=5k_1$ and $b=5k_2$. Therefore, $25ab^2=3125k_1k_2^2$ and $a^4+b^4=625(k_1^4+k_2^4)$. So $d|625(k_1^4+k_2^4+5k_1k_2^2)$. Does this mean that $d|625$?

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, we see that $625$ divides both number, so that $625|d$.  Now the question is, can $d$ be greater than $625$?  We have that $\gcd(k_1,k_2)=1$.  Any prime $p\neq5$ that divides $3125k_1k_2^2$ divides one of $k_1,k_2$ but not the other, so it doesn't divide $k_1^4+k_2^4$.  The question remains whether it's possible that $5\mid(k_1^4+k_2^4)$.

Consider $k^4\pmod{10}$, that is, the last digit of $k^4$.  A little arithmetic shows that the only possibilities are $0,1,5,6$.  The only way to get a number ending in $0$ or $5$ is to add two chosen from $\{0,5\}$, so that both $k_1,k_2$ would have to be divisible by $5$, contradiction.

Therefore, the gcd is $625$.

Comment: Great. Thank you! Another question: can you think of a more direct or general way to solve a problem of this sort? If you don't, that's okay, but if anyone else had different way to solve I'd like to hear it too! I took this problem from an exam paper, and I can't think of that last part about the digits being the expected answer.

Comment: It’s possible the intended way was to use $\mod 5$ instead of $\mod 10$. This simplifies the calculations a fair bit, especially because you can use FLT.